# Configure service with user-related parameters in .NET Core dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have service class which loads data from external service. This service needs API key which loads from db and unique for every user.

```
public class GoogleCloudService
{
    private readonly ILogger<GoogleCloudService> logger;

    public GoogleCloudService(string key)
    {
        Key = key;
        logger = Startup.ServiceProvider.GetService<ILogger<GoogleCloudService>>();
    }

    public string Key { get; set; }

    public async Task<string> ImageTextRecognizeAsync(byte[] imageBytes, string type = "TEXT_DETECTION", string languageHints = "en-t-i0-handwrit")
    {
        string url = "https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate"
            + "?key=" + Key;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                var values = new
                {
                    requests = new[]
                    {
                        new {
                            image = new { content = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes) },
                            features = new[] { new { type = type } },
                            imageContext = new { languageHints = new[] { languageHints } }
                        }
                    }
                };

                var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, values);

                try
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerOptions();
                    jsonSettings.Converters.Add(new DynamicJsonConverter());
                    dynamic responseJson = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<dynamic>(jsonSettings);

                    if (responseJson is not null && responseJson.responses is not null && responseJson.responses[0] is not null && responseJson.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation is not null)
                    {
                        return responseJson.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation.text;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return null;
                    }

                    throw new HttpRequestException();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ex.Data.Add("Request", await response.RequestMessage.ToRawAsync());
                    ex.Data.Add("Response", await response.ToRawAsync());

                    throw;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                logger.LogError(ex, "Возникла ошибка при отправке запроса в Google Cloud.");
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
var gService = new GoogleCloudService(entityDB.GoogleApiKey);
string text = await gService.ImageTextRecognizeAsync(imageBytes);
```

Everything works fine, but I think using global ServiceProvider from static Startup.ServiceProvider is not a good idea.
How can I eliminate service locator pattern and configure service key dynamically by user in code? What are best practices?

Comment: `public GoogleCloudService(string key, ILogger<GoogleCloudService> logger)` - the constructor must accept one more parameter

Comment: [HttpClient](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-5.0#remarks) is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application.

Comment: Problem not in a HttpClient - it's just an example. Problem in using dependency injection with other params from DB.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code after an answer has been posted. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my observations:

- `Startup.ServiceProvider.GetService<ILogger<GoogleCloudService>>();`: As you might know Inversion of Control are usually achieved either via Dependency Injection or via Service Locator. The later one [should be avoided](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) if possible. So, please prefer Dependency Injection:

```
public class GoogleCloudService
{
    private readonly ILogger<GoogleCloudService> logger;

    public GoogleCloudService(string key, ILogger<GoogleCloudService> logger)
    {
        Key = key;
        this.logger = logger;
    }
```

- `public string Key { get; set; }`: Do you really need to expose this as public? Do you really need to allow external modification?

  - If no then `private readonly string key` would be sufficient or if you stick to property then `private string Key { get; init; }`
- `using (var client = new HttpClient())`: You don't need to create and [dispose an HttpClient](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) for each and every request. Please prefer a static `HttpClient` per domain or use `HttpClientFactory` if you can.
- `Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes)`: I would suggest to perform some sort of preliminary check to make sure that `imageBytes` are not `null` and contains some data
- `var jsonSettings = new JsonSerializerOptions();` This could be declared as static because this is not changing from request to request
- `await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<dynamic>`: Try to avoid deserializing data into `dynamic`. Please create a concrete class, which could be used as the contract between your client and the service provider. `dynamic` can hide a lot of problems
- `responseJson.responses[0] is not null`: This might cause `OutOfRangeException` if the `responses` is defined but empty. Please check the collection's length as well prior accessing a member directly
- `throw new HttpRequestException();`: According to my understanding you will never reach this code. The `else` block is also unnecessary:

```
if (responseJson is not null 
    && responseJson.responses is not null 
    && responseJson.responses.Length > 0
    && responseJson.responses[0] is not null 
    && responseJson.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation is not null)
{
    return responseJson.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation.text;
}

return null;
```

- `ex.Data.Add("Request", await response.RequestMessage.ToRawAsync());` Capturing the whole request-response might be expensive if their body are too lengthy. It might make sense to truncate them. Please bear in mind that you already have `values` variable which contains the request body. Please also bear in mind that you are not capture headers, which might contain valuable information
- `catch(Exception ex)`: You can get rid of the outer try-catch if you perform preliminary checks

```
if(imageBytes == null || (imagesBytes != null && imagesBytes.Length < 1))
   return ...

var values = new ...
var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(url, values);

try
{
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    ...
    {
        return responseJson.responses[0].fullTextAnnotation.text;
    }
    return null;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ex.Data.Add("Request", await response.RequestMessage.ToRawAsync());
    ex.Data.Add("Response", await response.ToRawAsync());

    logger.LogError(ex, "Возникла ошибка при отправке запроса в Google Cloud.");
}
```

---

**UPDATE**: Reflect to comment

You can create a Factory method which is responsible for creating `GoogleCloudService` instances. You can take advantage `ILoggerFactory` ([Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.iloggerfactory)) to avoid Service Locator.

```
public class GoogleCloudServiceFactory: ICloudServiceFactory
{
   private readonly ILoggerFactory loggerFactory;
   public GoogleCloudServiceFactory(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   {
      this.loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
   }

   public ICloudService Create(string key)
   {
      return new GoogleCloudService(key, loggerFactory);
   }
}
```

Usage

```
foreach (var entityDB in entities)             
{                 
    ICloudService gService = serviceFactory.Create(entityDB.GoogleApiKey);                 
    string text = await gService.ImageTextRecognizeAsync(entityDB.ImageBytes);             
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question is how to use the service without service locator in a scenario like this:
`foreach (var entityDB in entities)
            {
                var gService = new GoogleCloudService(entityDB.GoogleApiKey);
                string text = await gService.ImageTextRecognizeAsync(entityDB.ImageBytes);
            }`

Comment: @sDima I've extended my post to reflect to your question. Please check it.

Answer (score 1):

why not use `Request` headers?

You can register the `IHttpContextAccessor` service at `Startup` :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllers();

    //register IHttpContextAccessor
    services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
}
```

now, configure your service to construct with `IHttpContextAccessor` :

```
public class GoogleCloudService
{
    private readonly ILogger<GoogleCloudService> _logger;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public GoogleCloudService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, ILogger<GoogleCloudService> logger)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _logger = logger;
        
        // Get apiKey
        Key = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers["apiKey"];
    }
    
    // ..etc.
}
```

now, everything can be configured from the controllers side. Suppose you need to validate the header and do some extra action based on it for every request, to do that, we can add a `FilterAction` and register it, something like this :

```
 // this filter will be executed on each request. 
public class ApiKeyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public async override Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context , ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {            
        // get ApiKey  
        var ApiKey = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["ApiKey"];
        
        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ApiKey))
        {
            // the apiKey is lost or user is not authenticated
            // redirect user to the proper page 
        }
        
        // what you need to do with the ApiKey ?
        // do some async actions ..etc. 
        await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
    }
}
```

now, register this filter at `Startup` :

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
    {
        options.Filters.Add(new ApiKeyFilterAttribute());
    });
}
```

Comment: The ApiKey is not obtained from the request and has nothing to do with authorization. It is in the database. I am making requests to a remote service using user keys on their behalf. The question is not the key, but how to organize dependency injection with passing different parameters.

Comment: @sDima I see now,  so you need a way to use DI for passing different parameters that would be initialized from the database to be reused across the project ? is that what you ask for ?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I have updated the example for clarity. I know I can just add a service to a dependency container with a default constructor and manually assign each property before each use, but is that the right approach?

Comment: @sDima if i'm following your correctly, I think you're looking for `IOptions` service, which you can bind your class of parameters, and reuse it where you needed through DI. Have you thought about it ?

Comment: IOptions is static, but I need the ability to call the service in a loop with different parameters.

Comment: @sDima you can use `IOptionsSnapshot` then, this is a scoped service, and can be updated on each request.

Comment: How to use IOptionsSnapshot in a scenario like this:
`foreach (var entityDB in entities)
            {
                var gService = new GoogleCloudService(entityDB.GoogleApiKey);
                string text = await gService.ImageTextRecognizeAsync(entityDB.ImageBytes);
            }`